# Using Rules to Convert Auth0 Token

Tags: jwt, auth0

I'm currently using auth0-js library v8 to authenticate users against Auth0. This library forcibly signs JWT tokens using RS256. Temporarily, I would like to decode the token and re-encode it using HS256/my current CLIENT SECRET, before returning the token in the authenticated response. Can I use Auth0 rules for that? Any idea how?

Comment: No, rules cannot be used to do this. Why do you want to not use RS 256? Can you share more details on your use case ?

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to overcome a temporary limitation in graph.cool that can only understand HS256 tokens for the time being.

Comment: @Sammy have you found a way for get HS256 token? I also struggle with auth0 and Graph.cool :-(

Answer (score 0):

Reacting to Pawel's comment up there: this is no longer an issue! With Graphcool [resolvers](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/functions/resolvers-su6wu3yoo2) you can now extend your schema to handle authentication (amongst others) whatever way you deem suitable.